# Move Columns Based on Array of Column Numbers

Tags: google-apps-script

I have an array of columns that I want to keep. I've got that code below:

```
  //Keep only columns user wants.
  if(keepColumnsArray != ""){    
    for (var col = sourceShtLC; col > 0; col--) {
      if (keepColumnsArray.indexOf(col) == -1) {
        // This isn't a keeper, delete it
        destSht.deleteColumn(col);
      }    
    }
  }
```

What I'd like to do now is arrange the columns following the order the `keepColumnsArray` has them.

Samples:

```
var keepColumnsArray = [3,2,1,4,5]
```

Using the above sample I want column 3 to be the first column, column 2 to be the second, column 1 to be the 3rd, column 4 to be the 4th and column 5 to be the 5th.

Current Order:

[image]

The order I want it. As you can see it's the same order the array is in.

[image]

Solution:
Rather than deleting the columns first I used code from the accepted answer to move the columns I want to keep to the front. In this case Columns 1 through 5 I kept and then I deleted the rest because all that was left were columns I did not need. Here is my final code.

```
  //Use order of array to reorder columns and then delete the rest of the columns
  var offset = keepColumnsArray.length;
  destSht.insertColumns(1, offset);
  keepColumnsArray.forEach(function(e, i) {
    destSht.getRange(1, (e + offset), destSht.getLastRow(), 1).copyTo(destSht.getRange(1, i + 1));
  });
  destSht.deleteColumns(offset + 1, sourceShtLC);  //Keep only columns user wants.
```

Comment: In order to help to think of your goal, can you provide the sample value of `keepColumnsArray` and the sample Spreadsheet including the input and output you expect? Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: Ok. I added that info. Sorry I wasn't clear before.

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding the information. I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You want to arrange the columns on the sheet with `var keepColumnsArray = [3,2,1,4,5]`.

  - For example, you want to arrange from the columns `1, 2, 3, 4, 5` to `3, 2, 1, 4, 5`.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

### Pattern 1:

In this case, `moveColumns` is used. The flow of this script is as follows.

1. Create an array object including the original index and destination index of the columns.
2. Sort the array.
3. The columns are arranged using `moveColumns`.

#### Sample script:

```
function myFunction() {
  var keepColumnsArray = [3,2,1,4,5];

  var obj = keepColumnsArray.reduce(function(ar, e, i) {
    ar.push({from: i + 1, to: e});
    return ar;
  }, []);
  obj.sort(function(a, b) {return  a.to < b.to ? -1 : 1});
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  obj.forEach(function(o) {
    var columnSpec = sheet.getRange(1, o.from);
    if (o.from != o.to) sheet.moveColumns(columnSpec, o.to);
    for (var j = 0; j < obj.length; j++) {
      if (obj[j].from < o.from) obj[j].from += 1;
    }
  });
}
```

### Pattern 2:

In this case, each column is copied with the order of `keepColumnsArray` using a temporal sheet, and put the arranged columns to the original sheet.

#### Sample script:

```
function myFunction() {
  var keepColumnsArray = [3,2,1,4,5];

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var temp = ss.insertSheet("temp");
  sheet.activate();
  keepColumnsArray.forEach(function(e, i) {
    sheet.getRange(1, e, sheet.getLastRow(), 1).copyTo(temp.getRange(1, i + 1));
  });
  temp.getDataRange().copyTo(sheet.getRange(1, 1));
  ss.deleteSheet(temp);
}
```

#### Reference:

- [moveColumns(columnSpec, destinationIndex)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#moveColumns(Range,Integer))

### Added:

From [OP's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60104574/move-columns-based-on-array-of-column-numbers/60105370#comment106306197_60105370), In this sample script, the columns are inserted and put the arranged columns.

> Instead of creating a temp sheet can we not add 5 columns to the beginning and then copy them to those new columns?

#### Sample script:

```
function myFunction() {
  var keepColumnsArray = [3,2,1,4,5];

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var offset = keepColumnsArray.length;
  sheet.insertColumns(1, offset);
  keepColumnsArray.forEach(function(e, i) {
    sheet.getRange(1, e + offset, sheet.getLastRow(), 1).copyTo(sheet.getRange(1, i + 1));
  });
  sheet.deleteColumns(offset, offset);
}
```

Comment: Instead of creating a temp sheet can we not add 5 columns to the beginning and then copy them to those new columns? Could use destSht.insertColumnsBefore(1, keepColumnsArray.length)

Comment: @DanCue Thank you for replying. I think that it is possible. But when you want to arrange the columns, how about the sample script of pattern 1?

Comment: @DanCue For your replying, I added one more sample script. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: We're headed in the right direction with the last sample. Unfortunately, I get an error Exception: The coordinates of the source range are outside the dimensions of the sheet.

Comment: If I change copyTo to moveTo it will go through with the function but then empty columns are left between columns before the deleteColumns takes place.

Comment: @DanCue Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, I cannot image your current script from your replying. Because in my environment, I could confirm that the 3 scripts worked. So can you provide your current script? If you can do, please add it to your question. By this, I would like to modify it.

Comment: @DanCue If such error occurs even when you don't modify my script, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet for replicating your issue including your script?

Comment: I solved the issue. I was thinking about it wrong. Rather than delete the columns I don't want and then sort, I moved the columns I wanted to the front using your code and then deleted the columns after. I'll post my solution on my post and accept yours. Thanks!

Comment: @DanCue Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 2):

**Problem**

1. Filtering out columns by criteria
2. Reordering columns by criteria

**Solution**

First, add logic that filters and sorts your values. One of the possible algorithms is as follows: **map** source such that each row is **mapped** such that each cell is cell by **order index** from source and filter columns such that its index is a **keep index**.

```js
var input = [3,2,1,4,5];

var initial = [
  ['Column1','Column2','Column3','Column4','Column5','Column6','Column7'],
  ['2first','2second','2third','2fourth','2fifth','2sixth','2seventh'],
];

function filterAndReorder (source,order) {
  return source
  .map(function(row,r){        
    return row.map(function(cell,c){
      return source[r][order[c]-1];
    })
    .filter(function(cell,c){
      return cell !== undefined;
    });
  })
}

var output = filterAndReorder(initial,input);

console.log(output);
```

Then, use the fact that `setValues()` accepts 2D `Array` and replaces `Range` contents:

```
var lrow = destSht.getLastRow();
var range = destSht.getRange(1,1,lrow,5);
var inputVals = range.getValues();

var keepColumnsArray = []; //obtain the keep Array somehow;

var outputVals = filterAndReorder(inputVals,keepColumnsArray);

var range.setValues(outputVals);
```

**Notes**

1. `keepColumnsArray` is an `Array` so the `!= ""` is redundant (unless you actually expect it to be an empty string in which case I would suggest rewriting the logic that outputs the `Array` - it will save you at least 1 op + save you debug time in the future).
2. As a general rule of thumb, please, avoid using I/O as much as possible (especially in a loop) and keep input close to start of the logic and output to the end. `deleteColumn` is an I/O and thus should at least be performed in batch.
3. **UPD** if you reorder is partial (that is, there are columns unchanged), you can fold the resulting empty columns via [`deleteColumns()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#deleteColumns(Integer,Integer))

**References**

1. `filter()` method [ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) on MDN
2. `map()` method [ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on MDN